# Properly implementing IComparable<T> on a Struct in C# 8 with Nullable set to enable

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-8.0

What is now the proper way to implement CompareTo in C# 8 when Nullable is enabled. The implement interface feature in Visual Studio suggested this signature:

```cs
public struct PackageVersionNumber : IComparable<PackageVersionNumber>
{
    public int Major { get; }

    public int Minor { get; }

    public int Patch { get; }

    public int CompareTo([AllowNull] PackageVersionNumber other)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

PackageVersionNumber is a struct in this case and really shouldn't be null. Can I safely delete the `[AllowNull]` attribute from the argument or do I need to leave it there and really check for null. Or is this a bug?

Comment: If `PackageVersionNumber` is a struct it can't be null. `AllowNull`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know, hence my question. I'll add the part about the struct to the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**
You can safely remove this attribute from the method signature.

**Explanation**

In your `CompareTo` method signature, the struct is passed by-value and is not marked as nullable. This is the correct interface implementation for your `PackageVersionNumber` struct.

That means, the `other` argument value cannot be `null` no matter what you do.

You cannot even write `if (other == null)` - that will produce a compiler error (unless you overload the `==` operator for `PackageVersionNumber` what you should really consider for a struct, by the way).

But even with an overloaded `==` operator, the `if (other == null)` comparison will *always* yield `false` - so there is no need in that check. The overloaded operator will allow the compiler to implicitly cast `PackageVersionNumber` to nullable `PackageVersionNumber?` in the comparison - and you'll get a CS0472 warning:

> The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'PackageVersionNumber' is never equal to 'null' of type 'PackageVersionNumber?'

I suppose that the "Implement interface" feature in Visual Studio doesn't consider the type on which the interface is implemented and always uses the same snippet with that `AllowNullAttribute`.

That attribute is indeed useful for implementing the interface for non-nullable reference types. While they are "logically" non-nullable, there is still a way to get a `null` value at runtime - so a null check is required to avoid a `NullReferenceException`. Furthermore, you have to ensure the backwards compatibility with assemblies compiled with C#7.x and below - `IComparable<T>` perfectly allows `null` for `T`s that are reference types.